# How to change the value of variable based on the available values in List

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

I need your help in changing the value of a `boolean` variable based on the available values in a List. I defined a class called `Student`:

```
public class Student {
    private Integer id;//Getter and Setter
    private String name;//Getter and Setter
    private String location;//Getter and Setter
    private String remarks;//Getter and Setter
    private boolean disable;//Getter and Setter

    public Student(Integer id, String name, String location, String remarks, boolean disable){
                    this.id = id;
                    this.name = name;
                    this.location = location;
                    this.remarks=remarks;
                    this.disable=disable;
            }
```

By default in the bean, the value of the disable is true. In the program, I have two lists which are `employeeList` and `selectedEmployees`. The `employeeList` has the values and the `selectedEmployees` List has the selected values:

```
private List<Student> employeeList = new ArrayList<Student>();
private List<Student> selectedEmployees;
private boolean disable;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    //add Employees
    disable=true;
    Student w1 = new Student(111, "AAAA", "ZZZZ", "", disable);
    Student w2 = new Student(222, "CCCCC", "ZZZZZ", "OUT", disable);
    Student w3 = new Student(333, "BBBBBB", "YYYYYYY", "IN", disable);

    employeeList.add(w1);
    employeeList.add(w2);
    employeeList.add(w3);

}
```

However, I am having a method which is called `EnableInputText` that will be called to check if any of the above values is in the `selectedEmployees` List, then it should change the value of the `disable` variable to `false`:

```
public void EnableInputText(SelectEvent event) {


for(int i=0;i<=selectedEmployees.size();i++){ 
    for(int j=0;j<=employeeList.size();j++){          
    if(selectedEmployees.get(i).getId().equals(employeeList.get(j).getId()))
    {
       selectedEmployees.get(j).setDisable(false);
       break;
    }
   }
 }

}
```

But with the above code, I am getting the error:

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3    at
>   java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(ArrayList.java:547)    at
>   java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:322)

Comment: Change the `<=` to `<` in your loop conditions.  If the size of your list is `3`, the only legal indexes you can access are `0`, `1`, and `2`.

Comment: If you use for-each style loops like `for (Student student : list)` you won't ever have this sort of problem.

Comment: @azurefrog Yes you are correct

Answer (score 0):

```
selectedEmployees.get(j).setDisable(false);
```

i think you meant to use i instead of j for that line?

or on the flip side probably:

```
employeeList.get(j).setDisable(false);
```

Comment: Check azurefrog answer in the comments. That is the right answet